# Create network with SSID containing null characters (\0)

Tags: wireless-networking

According to the [802.11 standard](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee802/download/802.11-2012.pdf), a wireless network SSID is an octet string of length 0-32. This means in theory that "\0\0\0" (i.e. three null characters) is a valid SSID. Although this sounds crazy, I have seen things like this in the wild. I'm trying to test some software which scans for wireless networks, and need to test that  it can handle such crazy SSIDs (which can trip up string processing functions). However I'm struggling to create an ad-hoc network with an SSID that contains null characters. I have tried using `iwconfig` on linux, and can set the SSID, but not to anything containing null. Any ideas about how I could create a network with an SSID containing null characters? Linux or Windows based solutions are acceptable, and a modest amount of code writing would be OK.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please provide constructive feedback if you think the question is badly worded or not appropriate for this stackexchange.

Comment: According to the description in hostapd.conf and wpa_supplicant.conf, the ssid there can also be entered in hexadecimal, thus allowing anything but I could never get it done with my attempts

Answer (score 1):

In Kali Linux, and Ubuntu this is a driver issue. The \0\0\0 ssids are always a 5ghz network in my scans. The driver picks it up in 2.4GHZ scans and doesn't display the 5ghz SSID correctly.

Try writing the bssid's down and then force the adapter into the band you want. You should then see the correct ssid's attached to the bssid in the scans. This has been an annoying issue for a while now in Kali. Usually I see this with cards/adapters that also have the "negative one" problem.

Comment: Thanks, will have a look. What do you mean by the "negative one" problem?

Comment: It's a reference to airodump-ng. https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?18541-Airodump-fixed-channel-mon0-1

Answer (score 1):

You may use **hostapd** on linux to create an access point that broadcasts an SSID with null characters.

This can be accomplished via the **ssid2** setting in the hostapd configuration file. For example setting the following in your hostapd.conf:

```
ssid2=P"\x00\x00\x00"
```

will cause hostapd to advertise with an SSID of three null (\0) bytes.

More info about the **ssid2** setting here: https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/hostapd/hostapd.conf